# Fabric sudo access

Tags: python, python-2.7, sudo, put, fabric

I want to use sudo access with put function in fabric

as is specified in the doc http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html

```
cxn.put(os.getcwd()+"/configuration/supervisor/master.conf","/etc/supervisor/conf.d/master.conf",use_sudo=True)
```

> ERROR:  TypeError: put() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_sudo'

I want access sudo to run this command with user.

Help?

Comment: Why not using `cxn.run()` and replace your put with pure linux command because `fabric sudo command` had and still have some issues! 
Tip: use the newer version of Fabric, is more intuitive and more stable

Comment: Thanks, 
Here i am using fabric2, which is already newer version of Fabric only.
using `cxn.put( )` because this is how fbric2 works. I was having issue `Sudo` with put i was moving `master.conf`, but now i changed it to.


```
confLoc=pwd+"/master.conf"
    cxn.put(os.getcwd()+"/configuration/supervisor/master.conf",confLoc)
    cxn.sudo('mv '+confLoc+' /etc/supervisor/conf.d')
```

Comment: It' good you are using fabric2, but you have referred to fabric 1.14 docs

Comment: oh yes, but this is the only syntex i have got from fabric.